# Show that there exist precisely four non-negative integers $n$ for which $f(f(n))=f(n).$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

> Question: Let $f:\mathbb{W}\to\mathbb{W}$ be the function defined by $f(0)=0,f(1)=1,$ and $f(n)=f(n-1)+f(n-2)$ for $n\ge 2$, where $\mathbb{W}$ is the set of all nonnegative integers. Show that there exist precisely four non-negative integers $n$ for which $f(f(n))=f(n).$

Clearly the recurrence relation stated above helps us in stating that $f(n)=F_n, \forall n\in\mathbb{W},$ where $F_n$ denotes the $n^{th}$ term of the Fibonacci sequence. Now it is easy to observe that $n=0,1,2,5$ satisfies the equation $f(f(n))=f(n)$.

But how to prove that the equation $f(f(n))=f(n)$ does not have any solution for any $n>5$? A hint would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Prove that for $n \gt 5$, you always have $f(n) \gt n$ (e.g., use strong induction, so if $f(k) \gt k$ and $f(k + 1) \gt k + 1$, then $f(k + 2) = f(k) + f(k + 1) \gt k + (k + 1) = 2k + 1 \gt k + 2$). This will then give $f(f(n)) \gt f(n)$.

Comment: I had some typos in the question. Kindly have a look at the question now.

Comment: @SanketBiswas Thanks for letting me know. I didn't notice that typo originally. Also, although you might not need it, I added some extra details about how to prove what I was stating using strong induction.